# Does the Doppler effect work either way?

Tags: waves, visible-light, doppler-effect, redshift

I know that the Doppler effect is when waves get compressed or stretched. For light this causes red shifts and blue shifts. My question is if we were moving towards or away from the source of light, would we observe a shift even if the source is stationary.

Comment: Yes, you would.

Comment: Stationary to what?

Comment: Just try it by speeding past a stationary police car with its sirens on. 

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_relativity 
                      ''According to the first postulate of the special theory of relativity:[3]
Special principle of relativity: If a system of coordinates K is chosen so that, in relation to it, physical laws hold good in their simplest form, the same laws hold good in relation to any other system of coordinates K' moving in uniform translation relatively to K.
— Albert Einstein: The Foundation of the General Theory of Relativity, Part A, §1""